# Generate a list/reference of dynamically added inputs

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working in an CMS called RiSE, and have many constraints.  I am also thinking in PHP while trying to output C#.

I have a contact form that is being dynamically generated by being put together by "iParts".  Each iPart includes an ASCX file into the wizardry of templates and junk.

As an example, I could have 2 iParts that each add a text box.  How do I generate a list of these 2 text boxes that I can recall after post as to get the values?

What I am doing now, and almost works....

I have what I think is called a controller, and it (I think) defins a property like so;

```
namespace EmailForm
{
  [DataContract(Name = "EmailForm")]
  public class EmailForm : iPartCommonBase
  {
    public static Dictionary<String, String> inputs = new Dictionary<String, String>();
  }
}
```

Now in my (I think) Controller, I add to the `Dictionary inputs` like so;

```
EmailForm.inputs[randId + "_" + inputEmailLabel.ToString()] = input.UniqueID;
```

What I end up with is a key value pair list that contains a label prefixed with some random string (to prevent crashes/overwrites) and the id.

When the form is submitted I loop through the dictionary and use the ID string to access the posted value.  Pretty straight forward, BUT, if I reload the page say 3 times before filling the form and hitting submit, I end up with 6 entries into my Dictionary, all but the last 2 reference non-existant ID's.

What should I do differently? (and unfortunately, use LAMP is not an option)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I have found a simple solution, I think it's a hack, but so is ASP

```
if (Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains(post.Value))
{
    emailBody.Add(post.Key.Substring(8) + ": " + Request.Form[post.Value]);
}
```

The Dictionary still contains "rogue" entries, but I filter them out by existing post data.